# Getting a deeper understanding of the similarities & differences between the words "offhand/offhanded" , "facile" & "glib"

Tags: meaning-in-context, differences, context, negative-raising

> (reference:
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/offhand  )
>
> offhand
>
> not friendly, and showing little interest in other people in a way
> that seems slightly rude:

> (reference:  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glib
> )
>
> glib
>
> speaking or spoken in a confident way, but without careful thought or
> honesty:

> ( reference:
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/facile
>
> facile
>
> A facile remark or theory is too simple and has not been thought about
> enough:

I know that offhand/offhanded is generally suggests a negative context.

However, could someone please elaborate on the similarities and/or differences between the aforementioned words ( possibly with examples in sentences ) ?

Comment: What about the definitions is unclear to you? Have you looked at the usage examples in the dictionary? They are all somewhat negative descriptions. A person being offhand is dismissive of others; a glib salesman or politician isn't trustworthy; a facile person is thoughtless.

Comment: Are you sure that *offhand* isn't often neutral? "It was an offhand comment. Don't hold him to such a casual remark."

Comment: You (the OP) should look at more dictionaries, preferably those with multiple definitions and usage examples. Merriam-Webster's definitions are clearly different, with "[offhand](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offhand)" not usually negative, and the others not normally complimentary but not necessarily bad. It helps if you have a particular situation in mind, otherwise we could give a long list of irrelevant usages.

Comment: Also, [jejune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btDqtCGIgGY)

Comment: @Mitch Oh yeah, that one's indubitably in the selfsame ætherial register as the supercited glosses domicile within, natch.

Comment: "facile" means that you're treating something as simpler than it actually is, ignoring complicating details.

Comment: @tchrist 'jejune' and 'facile' are closer in register than either is (or is it are) to 'glib' and likewise all three to 'offhand'. Yet they all share some denotation, though not exactly synonymous. A good answer would touch on these nuances.

Comment: "Offhand" and "offhanded" do not usually have any negative connotations, but are just used to refer to a remark that was casual, informal, not based on careful thought.